# Autopopulating state while user enters zipcode

Tags: html, jquery

We are trying to use USPS API to get City and State attributes by passing ZIP code. API is working fine, but we need to use this API in our members registration form, where user enters ZIP code, then City and State should be auto filled in respective fields. This way user does not have to type City and State manually.

We would like to know what is the easiest and quicker way to achieve this in Django or other type web forms.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#InputZip").keyup(function() {
var el = $(this);
if (el.val().length === 5) {
$.ajax({
url: "https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=CityStateLookup&XML= 
<CityStateLookupRequest USERID=""><ZipCode ID='0'><Zip5>80023</Zip5> 
</ZipCode></CityStateLookupRequest>",
cache: false,
dataType: "xml",
type: "GET",
data: "zip=" + el.val(),
success: function(result, success){
$("#Inputstate").val(result.State);
}`enter code here`
});
}});
});

*html*
<input id="InputZip" name="Zip" placeholder="Zip Code" type="text">
<input id="Inputstate" name="state" placeholder="State" type="text">
```

Comment: can you provide a minimal working example where this API can be seen working. I am not able to call this URL at all. Its getting blocked.

Comment: "https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=CityStateLookup&XML= 
<CityStateLookupRequest USERID=""><ZipCode ID='0'><Zip5>80023</Zip5> 
</ZipCode></CityStateLookupRequest>", this is the api which i am using

Comment: make a working example of this api here: https://jsfiddle.net/  i do not think you can connect to this api via ajax

Comment: actually it is a usps based api . I am not able to get the output from my local computer. If you are able to modify this code according to Autopopulating  state while user enters a zipcode then that could be a great help